# Separate different and identical values in multidimensional associative array

Tags: php

I'm trying to make function which will go trough multidimensional array and get keys => pairs values only if they are identical in 
all arrays.

What I mean?

If you take a look at my example you will see how keys with `"Glavna Instanca"` have the same values in all arrays and it is `VR1`. 
Also, the same story is for `"Druga Instanca"` where the value is `"F2"`.

For keys `"Treca Instanca"` and `"Cetvrta Instanca"` we have different values and that values needs to be under the key `"differentValues"`.

```
<?php
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (
            [itemi] = Array
                (
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            [Glavna Instanca] = VR1
                            [Druga Instanca] = F2
                            [Treca Instanca] = VR3
                            [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                        )

                    [1] = Array
                        (
                            [Glavna Instanca] = VR1
                            [Druga Instanca] = F2
                            [Treca Instanca] = VR3
                            [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                        )

                    [2] = Array
                        (
                            [Glavna Instanca] = VR1
                            [Druga Instanca] = F2
                            [Treca Instanca] = VR333
                            [Cetvrta Instanca] = D444
                        )

                    [3] = Array
                        (
                            [Glavna Instanca] = VR1
                            [Druga Instanca] = F2
                            [Treca Instanca] = VR333
                            [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                        )
                );
        );
    );

?>
```

New array will need to be something like this:

```
$newArray = array(
         [Glavna Instanca] = VR1
         [Druga Instanca] = F2
         [differentValues] =>
            array(
                '0' => 
                array(
                    [Treca Instanca] = VR3
                    [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                );
                '1' =>
                array(
                    [Treca Instanca] = VR3
                    [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                );
                '2' => 
                array(
                    [Treca Instanca] = VR333
                    [Cetvrta Instanca] = D444
                );
                '3' => 
                array(
                    [Treca Instanca] = VR333
                    [Cetvrta Instanca] = D4
                );
            );
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'itemi' => array(
            array(
                'foo' => 'bar',
                'baz' => 'quz',
                'ASD' => '1',
                'DSA' => '11'
            ),
            array(
                'foo' => 'bar',
                'baz' => 'quz',
                'ASD' => '2',
                'DSA' => '22'
            ),
            array(
                'foo' => 'bar',
                'baz' => 'quz',
                'ASD' => '3',
                'DSA' => '33'
            ),
            array(
                'foo' => 'bar',
                'baz' => 'quz',
                'ASD' => '4',
                'DSA' => '44'
            ),
            array(
                'foo' => 'bar',
                'baz' => 'quz',
                'ASD' => '5',
                'DSA' => '55'
            )
        )
    )
);

$cleanArray = array();
foreach ($array[0] as $mainKey => $mainValue) {
    $a = true;
    $b = true;
    $c = true;
    $d = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mainValue); $i++) {
        if (isset($mainValue[$i+1])) {
            $a = ($a === true && ($mainValue[$i]['foo'] === $mainValue[$i+1]['foo'])) ?  true : false;
            $b = ($b === true && ($mainValue[$i]['baz'] === $mainValue[$i+1]['baz'])) ?  true : false;
            $c = ($c === true && ($mainValue[$i]['ASD'] === $mainValue[$i+1]['ASD'])) ?  true : false;
            $d = ($d === true && ($mainValue[$i]['DSA'] === $mainValue[$i+1]['DSA'])) ?  true : false;
        }
    }
    ($a === true) ? $cleanArray['foo'] = $mainValue[0]['foo'] : null;
    ($b === true) ? $cleanArray['baz'] = $mainValue[0]['baz'] : null;
    ($c === true) ? $cleanArray['ASD'] = $mainValue[0]['ASD'] : null;
    ($d === true) ? $cleanArray['DSA'] = $mainValue[0]['DSA'] : null;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($mainValue); $i++) {
        if ($a) {unset($mainValue[$i]['foo']);}
        if ($b) {unset($mainValue[$i]['baz']);}
        if ($c) {unset($mainValue[$i]['ASD']);}
        if ($d) {unset($mainValue[$i]['DSA']);}
    }
    $cleanArray['differentValues'] = $mainValue;
}
var_dump($cleanArray);
```

Hope that helps.